# mapping_msgs/PolygonalMap.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there

I'm trying to compile [this](http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Follower%20Robot) package but I get this error:

```
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o
  /home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/src/main.cpp:26:39: fatal error: mapping_msgs/PolygonalMap.h: No such file or directory
   #include <mapping_msgs/PolygonalMap.h>
                                         ^
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

I downloaded `mapping_msgs` and I copied it in lib folder and I added this to my `CMakeLists`, :

```
include_directories ("/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/lib/mapping_msgs/")
```

I had the same Error with `OpenNI` but when I added this to the `CMakeLists` it works:

```
include_directories ("/home/jros/rosPackage/testrospackageKinect/lib/OpenNI/Include/")
```

My question is for `mapping_msgs`, what should I do? and how can I deal with those kind of errors in `CMakeLists`?

I'm using rosbuild pacakge in ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232468/mapping_msgs/polygonalmap.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't manually hardcode your paths or copy files around, that's a recipe for desaster. Usually when you notice that some ros package like mapping_msgs is missing, you should first try installing it via apt-get (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-mapping-msgs`), or alternatively clone it into your catkin (or rosbuild) workspace. Then, catkin_make (or rosmake) should pick it up.

In this case however, I doubt that you'll get it running easily on Indigo. The wiki pages haven't been updated since 2011, and they mention "Electric" as the last supported ROS distro. A lot of stuff has changed since then. So if you really must use it, try setting up a Ubuntu 10.04 machine with ROS Electric; but I wouldn't recommend that; I'm not sure even whether the deb packages for Electric are still available.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-04-22**:
That's what I don't like about ROS, old package (not really old 2012) doesn't work in new versions.
Yes I do agree, it is not a good idea to be back to older ROS version and to Ubuntu 10 haha.
Thanks

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-22**:
That isn't a ROS problem, that's just the way it is. When all your dependencies are constantly evolving, there needs to be a maintainer that makes the required changes. WIthout a maintainer, a sofware package will not work in current versions.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-22**:
Also, ROS is for developers, not consumers. So if you are interested in getting that package running, feel free to port it to a new ROS distro. :)   I agree this is a problem (and it creates a lot of work for maintainers), but I don't see a way around it.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-04-22**:
Yes I would do that and import it to new version of ROS.

Consumers in its positive meaning, to make things progress faster, rather than working on something that has been already done by others :D Thanks for opensource.